# Git merge and push after

Tags: git

My git flow is very simple, I created the feature branch from master, then did some work on feature branch, issues add, commit, push and now I just need to merge it back to master. The steps for that are following: git checkout master, git merge feature and then I assume I need to issue push which is not really working (merge changes are not showing in the bitbucket), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message do you get?  Can you show some of the output from the commands you're trying to run?

Comment: Its nice to see people using commandline but why not just merge via the UI? It will tell you what went wrong. Also, before merging, make sure you are rebased off master else there might be merge conflicts and it wont let you merge.

Comment: I'm actually not getting any errors but the merge is not showing on the bitbucket site, and I have other developer telling me that the merge didn't happen and I was actually suggested to issue push

Comment: Do you mean the merge is not showing up in your history? If this is the case then you need to use git merge --no-ff feature. Otherwise it will most likely fast forward the merge.

Comment: On the branch on which you did the merge, what is the output of `git status`? And what is the result of `git branch -vv`?